# Print data from set in python

Tags: python, set, dataset

I've got a problem with python sets. I've got 2 sets:

```
l={'7': 44, '8': 65, '9': 66, '10': 50, '11': 61, '12': 62, '13': 53, '14': 78, '15': 61, '16': 23}
m={'7': 39, '8': 58, '9': 57, '10': 59, '11': 55, '12': 59, '13': 74, '14': 51, '15': 60, '16': 30}
```

And I have to print it like: `number, data_from_set_l, data_from_set_m`.
It'd look like:

```
7 44 39

8 65 58 

9 66 57
```

Do you have any idea about it? (I'm totally beginner in IT)

Comment: These are dictionaries, not sets

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but it will do what you asked in a literal sense:

```
for i in range(7, 17):
    print(i, l[str(i)], m[str(i)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the keys and print the value for respective key from both the dictionaries. Incase key is not available, it will print `None`

```
l={'7': 44, '8': 65, '9': 66, '10': 50, '11': 61, '12': 62, '13': 53, '14': 78, '15': 61, '16': 23}
m={'8': 58, '9': 57, '10': 59, '11': 55, '12': 59, '13': 74, '14': 51, '15': 60, '16': 30}

for key in l.keys():
    print(key, l.get(key), m.get(key))
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure given about is not set, it is dictionary.
Here is the code for the required output

```
l = {'7': 44, '8': 65, '9': 66, '10': 50, '11': 61, '12': 62, '13': 53, '14': 78, '15': 61, '16': 23}
m = {'7': 39, '8': 58, '9': 57, '10': 59, '11': 55, '12': 59, '13': 74, '14': 51, '15': 60, '16': 30}

for k in l.keys():
    print('{0} {1} {2}'.format(k, l[k], m[k]))
```